# Android ksoap2 adding object into object

Tags: java, android, xml, ksoap2

I am having a problem to get a respond from my webservice. I have something like this:

```
<AuthenticateUser xmlns="http://whatever">
  <request>
    <Username>string</Username>
    <Password>string</Password>
    <Partner>string</Partner>
  </request>
 </AuthenticateUser>
```

I don't know how to add those tree parameters to object`<request>`

Anybody can help?

Comment: I am also interested in the answer, while I am also finding a way to do that.

Answer (score 3):

```
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://whatever/AuthenticateUser";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "AuthenticateUser";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://whatever";
private static final String URL = "www.blablabla.com/test?WSDL";

SoapObject authenticateUser = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "request");
request.addProperty("Username","VALUE");
request.addProperty("Password","VALUE");
request.addProperty("Partner","VALUE");
authenticateUser.addSoapObject(request);
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Client' faultstring: 'Server was unable to read request. ---> There is an error in XML document (1, 367). ---> The specified type was not recognized: name=':' return this !!

Comment: The problem is i need to add another SoapObject not just `<request>' so i added two soap object like you did

Comment: authenticateUser.addSoapObject(request); and authenticateUser.addSoapObject(request2); but doesnt work

Comment: @Amalo you should open a new question because I answered this 6 year ago, things change between 2011 and now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390411/android-soap-web-service-call-with-multiple-soap-objects